# storing large xml in db2 xml data type

Tags: xml, insert, db2

We have a table with 10 columns, one of the column is of type xml.
I wrote an insert statement in db visualizer and tried to insert a record with all the values inline in the insert statement it gives the below error
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-102, SQLSTATE=54002,

I tried by changing the col type to clob and also tried XMLPARSE as shown in the  below link but the problem still remains, can you please help.:
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0022191.html

Comment: please provide more details on the table and the SQL statement. The error says that a string constant is too long.

Comment: create table test1 (col1 xml);

Comment: insert into test1 values ('<employee> ..........big xml of size 180kb....</employee>');

Comment: I am not sure if the error is because the whole insert statement is too big or because the xml value is too big in the insert query.

Comment: Which interface did you use to insert? Command line, JDBC/ODBC, ...?

Comment: And: Have you tried you '<emp>some smalll text </emp>' ? DB2 casts a string to XML and automatically parses it.

Comment: I used DB Visualizer software to run the query.

Comment: When i try <emp>some small xml</emp> it works fine , i get the error when i try <emp> ..........big xml of size 180kb....</emp>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a java program to run the insert using jdbc and it worked well.
i had to remove tabs, new line characters & escape double quotes from xml to assign it to a string variable.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the SQL error, you are limited to 32k of text data with the method you are using.

I found another reference on IBM's knowledgecenter that may help.

Place the XML into a stream file and then use the IMPORT command to input the data into your file.

Excerpt from [IBM DB2 Importing XML Data](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/c0024103.html)

> When importing data into an XML table column, you can use the XML FROM option to specify the paths of the input XML data file or files. For example, for an XML file "/home/user/xmlpath/xmldocs.001.xml" that had previously been exported, the following command could be used to import the data back into the table.
>
> > IMPORT FROM t1export.del OF DEL XML FROM /home/user/xmlpath INSERT INTO USER.T1

Comment: Hi can you please explain what is t1export.del, DEL and USER.T1 in the above command. I am also not sure what you meant by "Place the XML into a stream file". requesting you to please elaborate.

Comment: i copied the xml file to /home directory and ran the below command in putty 
db2 IMPORT FROM t1export.del OF DEL XML FROM /home                      INSERT INTO TEST2

My table TEST2 has a column of type xml
it did not work

Comment: From the syntax of the Import command:  "of DEL" identifies the file type.  "XML FROM <path>" identifies the xml path.   "USER.T1" identifies the Table name "dot" column name. [import command](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008304.html)